# Changing background color of button after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html code related to my button. As you can see, I've tried adding an id to reference it in CSS and JS.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 main">
  <h1>Constructive Design</h1>
  <p>
    Aenean fermentum vestibulum ipsum, ut pretium erat sodales sodales. Pellentesque quis orci vitae dui commodo sodales et ut quam. Etiam vitae egestas purus, ut malesuada enim.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="conbutton">Continue...</button>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for the main button without hover

```
.main button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 1.3px solid white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  color:white;;
}
```

This is the CSS for main button with hover

```
.main button:hover{
  background: transparent;
  color: #33ccff;
  border-color: #33ccff;
  transition:all 1.3s;
}
```

This is the CSS for the class .clbutton which I'll reference in JS.

```
.conbuttoncl{
  background: transparent;
}
```

This is the JS where I call that ID which I reference in HTML and add a class .clbutton to it. Let me know if I'm on the wrong track over here and if there's some other way to get at the same thing i.e changing background of button to transparent after my mouse clicks on it. I don't want the color of button to change to blue after a user clicks on it.

```
var conbutton = document.querySelector("#conbutton");
conbutton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  conbutton.classList.add(".conbuttoncl");
});
```

Comment: Get rid of the the . in conbutton.classList.add(".conbuttoncl"); so use this instead conbutton.classList.add("conbuttoncl");

Comment: I changed that but the background still changes to blue after click.

Comment: See my answer, you had another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed button colours on all of your different states to show this working as in your question you had them all set to `transparent`.

Issue 1:

```
conbutton.classList.add(".conbuttoncl");
```

should be

```
conbutton.classList.add("conbuttoncl"); //Without . in class name
```

Issue 2:
You've over specified the `.main` button class, which means it won't be overridden with the loose `.clbutton` class. Instead, just make it more precise, so this:

```
.conbuttoncl {
```

should be

```
.main button.conbuttoncl {
```

Working example:

```js
var conbutton = document.querySelector("#conbutton");
conbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  conbutton.classList.add("conbuttoncl");
});
```

```css
.main button {
  background: red;
  border: 1.3px solid white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  ;
}

.main button:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #33ccff;
  border-color: #33ccff;
  transition: all 1.3s;
}

.main button.conbuttoncl {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 main">
  <h1>Constructive Design</h1>
  <p>
    Aenean fermentum vestibulum ipsum, ut pretium erat sodales sodales. Pellentesque quis orci vitae dui commodo sodales et ut quam. Etiam vitae egestas purus, ut malesuada enim.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="conbutton">Continue...</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Do it Using JavaScript

```js
function bgchange() {
  document.getElementById("conbutton").style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
.main button {
  background: orange;
  border: 1.3px solid white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.main button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #33ccff;
  border-color: #33ccff;
  transition: all 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 main">
  <h1>Constructive Design</h1>
  <p>
    Aenean fermentum vestibulum ipsum, ut pretium erat sodales sodales. Pellentesque quis orci vitae dui commodo sodales et ut quam. Etiam vitae egestas purus, ut malesuada enim.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="conbutton" onclick="bgchange()">Continue...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say this is a better answer than mine as it's using ID instead of class, so gets rid of the need to over-specify the class. Although I would have the CSS in CSS instead of JS.

Comment: Thank you so much this means a lot actually, I am a beginner.

Comment: No problem, as a bit of advice, an event listener would be better as it saves for the need to add onclick into every button, but otherwise you beat me with the use of the ID.